# Spark RDD treeReduce vs Dataset reduce

Tags: apache-spark

Spark RDD has a variation of reduce called treeReduce, which is very efficient as it improves the parallelism by reducing as a hierarchy.

Spark Dataset doesn't have this variation. Is the Dataset's reduce implementation already efficient enough or there is some other way to achieve the same behaviour?